# How to edit info for tag wiki?

Tags: discussion

As far as I know,tag wiki comrises of two parts:**excerpt** and **full wiki**.

What can I add to those two.

**To excerpt**: The usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt, is a **short** blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

(It means no need of links,nothing)

**To full wiki**:

The full tag wiki is a **detailed** introduction to the topic, suitable as a destination for those curious about it: for example external links etc.,

This is what the site tag wiki help says.

---

Now my question,

I edited a tag [terminal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal) .In the **excerpt** there is link with *Markdown editing* which is not supported in that **excerpt** part.I removed and added to main **full wiki.**

But unfortunately that was rejected .[suggested-edits/2025](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2025).

I wonder ,Is the change is **superfluous** ?.Does the link is extremely reasonable in **excerpt** than **full wiki** part ?

This is not a *rant* ,I would like to know to avoid any future mistake(**if** it is a mistake).

---

**EDIT**:

Just I observed my pending edits and two edits are rejected by same reviewer.

see [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2029) and [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2030).

Have you seen any [Plagiarism](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) ?

I gave external link also.

**I am expecting moderators intervention.**

@LewisGoddard @RolandiXor @embik

Comment: @LewisGoddard , RolandiXor ,embik...I hope you all referred this post..=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2025 was a good edit. I think reviewers missed that you were editing the excerpt rather than the wiki body. It may help to put in an editing comment like “Remove formatting from excerpt since excerpts cannot use Markdown”.

Regarding https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2029 and https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2030, the reasons given for rejection make no sense to me. Not everyone here might know what Libreoffice is, so having an excerpt that defines it in one sentence is good. Providing links to the official site in the wiki body is also good. My objection would have been that your sentence had many grammatical errors, but that can easily be fixed by a reviewer with 4000 rep by clicking “Improve”.

(Tips: sentences start with a capital letter. A comma `,` does not start  a sentence. For most punctuation, there is no space before and a space after.)

Comment: thanks @Gilles...Is there any difference between reviewing tag edits and ordinary posts edit.Because when I review suggested edits in AU I can seel __improve__ option even I have less than 4k rep..

Comment: @Ravan You get the improve option if you were able to edit directly. For ordinary posts, this requires 1k rep on beta sites like Elementary, 2k on graduated sites like AU. For tag wikis, that requires 4k/20k.

Comment: thanks @Gilles ...I don't know that point.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I'm going to explain the issue from my perspective since I was involved with rejecting some of the tags you edited.

First, keep in mind that this is a new resource. Most of us who have decent reputation here did not have enough reputation on another StackExchange site and we're still trying to figure out how things work as we're gaining reputation.

Okay, so I rejected some of the edits (like [this one](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2023)) because they have some formatting issues. In the example I linked, there's absolutely no reason for the word "Slingshot" to be bold. I would also put the words "called Pantheon" in parenthesis and remove the italic from the word "Pantheon". And, to quote:

> .Also Slingshot, the default elementary OS application menu in Freya.

Here, there's an space character before the dot and no space character after it. The sentence after it really does not make any sense. Something like this would be better:

> Pantheon comes with its own set of applications: Slingshot (application launcher), Music, Videos, Midori (web browser), Geary (email management software), Pantheon Terminal (terminal emulator) and Pantheon Files (file browser).

Unfortunately, with my current reputation, I can only select one of the stated reasons for rejecting the edit. I can't add my own custom explanation of my decision.

As for the other edits, the issue I was having with them is that they are not specifically written with elementary OS in mind. Here's an example. In [this edit](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2000), you explained what LibreOffice is, but from a general perspective, not from a perspective of elementary OS. So, instead of:

> LibreOffice Portable is a full-featured office suite -- including a word processor, spreadsheet, presentation tool, drawing package and database

It should be something like:

> LibreOffice is a third-party office suite that can be installed from the Software Center. It comes with its own word processor (Writer), spreadsheet tool (Calc), presentation tool (Impress), drawing package (Draw) and database manager (Base).

Notice that the LibreOffice version available in the Software Center is not the portable version. Also, notice how I explained that LibreOffice does not come preinstalled with elementary OS and that it was not developed by the elementary team.

That "portable" word made me think that you have just copied the description from somewhere else and that's why I rejected it.

So, try to think from the elementary's perspective. If it's a third-party app, state that in the excerpt. Also, make sure your submission does not have any grammatical issues (place a space after the dot etc.) and I will accept it.

Comment: thanks for your response @r3bl =)..The reasons you are pointing out makes no sense (my opinion). You considered two examples.
1.Since `pantheon` is in bold,so you rejected?
2.The `libreoffice` edit rejected because of `portable `word, then what about this [http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2029]...

Comment: btw why you have chosen those two examples ?(I don't understand) I considered other three links which were answered by @Gilles..please try to answer for what I have asked.,... I appreciate you if you answer [http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/140/i-am-not-allowing-to-edit]...there you can explain your perspective...

Comment: Again, small grammar issues (no space after the `,` and `.` characters, `writer` and `calc` written without capitalizing the first letter, `include` should be changed to `includes`). I could not explain my rejection because I don't have the reputation needed to add custom explanations, so I picked one of the offered ones that seems like the most appropriate one. I kind of hoped that you will understand why I rejected them, correct the issues and submit a new request.

Comment: I respect you... , but I can't edit again,I was temporarily banned from editing =)

Comment: I did saw that other post you submitted, but decided to explain my reasons here because I honestly don't know why that "You are on the Featured tab" thingy is happening. This seemed like a more appropriate place to explain my reasons.

Comment: btw as you mentioned _small_ , but I feel nothing worth rejecting ,I have done many reviews in AU but never rejected  simple _small_ issues

Comment: I could have accepted them (but you'd need one or two more votes for them to be accepted), make an edit to them to fix those small issues and submit another edit request that fixes those issues, but that kind of feels like I would be doubling the work. I may have been a bit harsh (and I apologize for that), but I did that to keep the tag descriptions as clean of errors as possible. I hope you understand and I'm sorry you're not currently allowed to submit more edit requests. I was not aware that this could happen.