# I am not allowing to edit

Tags: discussion

I am not able to edit any tag. It showing the message "You are on the Featured tab."

How can I over come this.?

As far as I know , this is because many of my edits rejected, but with reference to [https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-to-edit-info-for-tag-wiki](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-to-edit-info-for-tag-wiki/139#139),this is not constructive  .

Also ,what is the way to  contact(communicate) with moderators regarding this?

I expected moderators intervention in my previous question [How to edit info for tag wiki?](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-to-edit-info-for-tag-wiki),but expecting atleast now.Otherwise there is no better option than leaving the site.

**EDIT**:

Now I came to know I temporarily banned from edits.

These are my rejected edits:

1.[review/suggested-edits/2000](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2000)

2.[review/suggested-edits/1999](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1999)

3.[review/suggested-edits/2023](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2023)

4.[review/suggested-edits/2025](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2025)

5.[review/suggested-edits/2030](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2030)

6.[review/suggested-edits/2029](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2029)

I don't know how many of them have correct reason to **reject**.

Comment: 1. Correctly rejected - not even meant to be about portable AFAIK. 2. Correctly rejected, you copied from https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/libreoffice/ 3. Correctly rejected You made 2 errors 4. Correctly rejected - that link was rightly removed. However, you also wrote "called as terminal" which is odd wording. 5. Correctly rejected - you made 3 mistakes and left off a word at the end - it reads as a copy paste, although I'm not sure if it is or not. 6. Correctly rejected - you copied from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice

Comment: @Tim thanks =) atleast one comment.Sorry I am not totally agreeing with you. Tim, look at the reasons for rejecting edits, the reasons makes no sense to me. Also the reasons are far away from the reasons you have mentioned.

Comment: Now one by one. 1. "portable" ? ok -I accept it 2. Copy from main site- ok I accept. 3.two errors? I am not accepting. 4. "called" does it have any synonym of **** . Just have a look [here](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/tags/terminal/info)-I hope you understand?

Comment: 5. This is ridiculous explanation from you, If your reason is correct, how @Daniel approved it ? Also I don't see any errors. 6. copied? have you seen external links ? refer [here](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)-- I think you no need to refer, since you are well rep and well qualified user in AU =)

Comment: 3. You spelt "provides" as "povides" and there is a space before the full stop not after it. 4. "Normally just called the terminal" would sound much better 5. He shouldn't have done tbh - "suit" should be "suite" and there is no space after the , and you miss a word at the end? 6. That's about answering, not tag wikis. You're not meant to copy paste into it.

Comment: @Tim 6. I not copied totally from those sites-IIRC I used own words and kept link as reference. I wonder does someone have copy rights over the particular words?--If that is not regarding tags, why they kept in reasons for rejection?